gdalwarp ERROR 1: Invalid pixel size for backmap
I used following command to generate geotiff file for VIIRS NetCDF file:
./gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs epsg:4326 -tr 0.0035 0.0035 -r near -te -70.18 -7.64 -43.96 30.91 dat.vrt i4b.tif
but failed with error message:
ERROR 1: Invalid pixel size for backmap.
Any ideas on how to fix it?
Thanks you very much.
